# Search for documents in SharePoint via Graph API

Tags: office-365, microsoft-graph

Is it possible to query for documents in SharePoint via Graph API?

The query should consider the document names or the complete document content (fulltext query).

1. I could not found any search request in the Graph API documentation:
   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint
2. There is a search parameter, but this is not available for SharePoint documents:
   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters
3. There is a filter parameter. But this parameter causes an error.
   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mysite/lists/123456/items?$filter=startswith(FileLeafRef,'query')

   What is the correct field for the document name?